# Нужна функция , которая будет выводить на консоль строки из массива строк(заданного) средней длинны и меньше

Tags: java

```
    `package lab2.tasks;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int strNumber = 0;
        StringDemo sd = new StringDemo();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Сколько строк желаете ввести?");
            try {
                Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
                strNumber = sn.nextInt();
                break;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка! Ведите целое число строк!");
            }
        }
        String strArr[] = new String[strNumber];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < strNumber; i++) {
            System.out.println("Введите строку " + (i + 1));
            strArr[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        int strSum = 0;
        int strAvg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            strSum += strArr[i].length();
        }
        strAvg = strSum / strNumber;
        System.out.println("Строки с длинной меньше средней и их длинны! ");
        do {
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println(strArr[i]);
            i++;
        }
        while (strArr.length <= strNumber);
    }
}
`
```

не получается сделать так, чтобы выводились именно строки с длинной меньше средней, не понимаю, как реализовать такую ф-цию. Длинны я уже посчитал, нашел среднюю, задача в том, как реализовать вывод.
это все , что придумал, заранее спасибо!

Comment: что именно вызывает у Вас затруднение и что именно у Вас не получается?

Comment: Сложность в том, что длинна строки в массиве, и среднее значение длинны - переменные типа инт, а сам массив состоит из переменных типа Строка

Comment: делайте проверку при выводе `if(strArr[i].length() <= strAvg ){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do-while` замените на

```
for (String line: strArr) {
    if (line.length() < strAvg) {
        sout(line + ", " + line.length();
    }
}
```

и зачем создали экземпляр класса? Вы же его не используете.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает как нужно :)